# using vtk for a sequence animation in python

Tags: python, animation, sequence, vtk

I have succesfully managed to make a 3d image of a pallet palletized with a number of boxes, using the following code.

```
import vtkmodules.all as vtk

#Create a renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)

# Create a render window
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
render_window.SetWindowName("Pallet Visualization")

# Create an interactor
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)

# create the pallet
pallet_elements = [
    (1200, 145, 22, 0, 0, 0),  
    (1200, 100, 22, 351, 0, 0),
    (1200, 100, 22, -351, 0, 0),
    (145, 100, 78, 351, 528, 50),
    (145, 100, 78, -351, 528, 50),
    (145, 100, 78, 351, -528, 50),
    (145, 100, 78, -351, -528, 50),
    (145, 100, 78, 351, 0, 50),
    (145, 100, 78, -351, 0, 50),
    (145, 145, 78, 0, 0, 50),
    (145, 145, 78, 0, 528, 50),
    (145, 145, 78, 0, -528, 50),
    (145, 800, 22, 0, 0, 101),
    (145, 800, 22, 0, 528, 101),
    (145, 800, 22, 0, -528, 101),
    (1200, 145, 22, 0, 0, 123),
    (1200, 145, 22, 328, 0, 123),
    (1200, 145, 22, -328, 0, 123),
    (1200, 100, 22, 328 / 2, 0, 123),
    (1200, 100, 22, -328 / 2, 0, 123)
]
for i, (width, length, height, x, y, z) in enumerate(pallet_elements):
    pallet = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
    pallet.SetXLength(length)
    pallet.SetYLength(width)
    pallet.SetZLength(height)

    pallet_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    pallet_mapper.SetInputConnection(pallet.GetOutputPort())

    pallet_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    pallet_actor.SetMapper(pallet_mapper)
    pallet_actor.SetPosition(x, y, z)
    pallet_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(198 / 255, 99 / 255, 60 / 255)
    renderer.AddActor(pallet_actor)

pallet_overlay = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
pallet_overlay.SetXLength(780)
pallet_overlay.SetYLength(1180)
pallet_overlay.SetZLength(2)

pallet_overlay_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
pallet_overlay_mapper.SetInputConnection(pallet_overlay.GetOutputPort())

pallet_overlay_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
pallet_overlay_actor.SetMapper(pallet_overlay_mapper)
pallet_overlay_actor.SetPosition(0, 0, 136)
pallet_overlay_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
renderer.AddActor(pallet_overlay_actor)

box_data = [
    # First Tier
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 0, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 201, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 402, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 603, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 0, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 201, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 402, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 603, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 0, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 201, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 402, 0),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 603, 0),
    # Second Tier
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 0, 0, 201),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 401, 0, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 0, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 201, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 402, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 603, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 0, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 201, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 402, 201),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 603, 201),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 0, 1003, 201),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 401, 1003, 201),
    # Third Tier
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 0, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 201, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 402, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 603, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 0, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 201, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 402, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 603, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 0, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 201, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 402, 403),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 603, 403),
    # Forth Tier
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 0, 0, 604),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 401, 0, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 0, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 201, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 402, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 201, 603, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 0, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 201, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 402, 604),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 602, 603, 604),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 0, 1003, 604),
    (2, 400, 200, 200, 401, 1003, 604),
    # Fifth Tier
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 0, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 201, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 402, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 0, 603, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 0, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 201, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 402, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 401, 603, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 0, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 201, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 402, 805),
    (1, 200, 400, 200, 802, 603, 805)
]

# correction for position on the pallet, for right corner being Pos(0, 0, 0) for Tier 1, 3, 5
correctionXPos = - 400
correctionYPos = - 300
correctionZPos = 238

# correction for position on the pallet, right corner being Pos (0, 0, 0) for Tier 2, 4, 6
correctionXPos2 = -200
correctionYPos2 = -500

for i, (tier, width, length, height, x, y, z) in enumerate(box_data):
    box = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
    box.SetXLength(width)
    box.SetYLength(length)
    box.SetZLength(height)

    box_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    box_mapper.SetInputConnection(box.GetOutputPort())

    if tier == 1:
        x_pos = x + correctionXPos
        y_pos = y + correctionYPos
        z_pos = z + correctionZPos
    else:
        x_pos = y + correctionYPos2
        y_pos = x + correctionXPos2
        z_pos = z + correctionZPos

    box_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    box_actor.SetMapper(box_mapper)
    box_actor.SetPosition(y_pos, x_pos, z_pos)
    box_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.2 + (i % 4) * 0.2, 0.4, 0.2 + (i % 3) * 0.2)  # Color each box differently
    renderer.AddActor(box_actor)


# Set up the camera
camera = vtk.vtkCamera()
camera.SetPosition(0, -3000, 4000)
camera.SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
renderer.SetActiveCamera(camera)

# Start the rendering loop
render_window.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

What I then wanted to do was to show the sequence of the boxes being placed on the pallet. I found an example of an animation of a square, moving across the screen, using the following code

```
import time

import vtkmodules.all

class vtkTimerCallback():
    def __init__(self, steps: int, actor: vtk.vtkActor, interactor:       vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor):
        self.timer_count = 0
        self.steps = steps
        self.actor = actor
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.timerID = None

    def execute(self, obj: vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor, event):
        step = 0

        while step < self.steps:
            print(self.timer_count)
            self.actor.SetPosition(self.timer_count / 100, self.timer_count / 100, 0)
            interactor = obj
            interactor.GetRenderWindow().Render()
            self.timer_count += 1
            step += 1

        if self.timerID:
            interactor.DestroyTimer(self.timerID)


def main():
    # Create the box
    box = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
    box.SetXLength(5)
    box.SetYLength(5)
    box.SetZLength(5)

    # sphere = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
    # sphere.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    # sphere.SetRadius(100)
    # sphere.SetPhiResolution(30)
    # sphere.SetThetaResolution(30)

    # Create mapper and actor
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(box.GetOutputPort())
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    # actor.SetPosition(0, 0, 0)

    # setup renderer and interactor
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    render_window.SetWindowName("Animation test")
    render_window.SetSize(600, 600)
    render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)

    # Add actor to the scene
    renderer.AddActor(actor)

    # Render and interact
    render_window.Render()
    renderer.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(0.5)
    render_window.Render()

    # initialize - prior to creating timer event
    interactor.Initialize()

    # sign up to timer event
    cb = vtkTimerCallback(200, actor, interactor)
    interactor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)

    cb.timerID = interactor.CreateRepeatingTimer(3000)

    # start the interaction and timer
    render_window.Render()
    interactor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works fine.

I then tried to modify the code to show 5 boxes on the screen in sequence. Meaning that in the first iteration there should be 1 square on the screen, in the second iteration 2 squares on the screen, and so on and so forth. But this code only presents 1 square in each iteration, following the sequence. Furthermore only the first square has the set color. The rest is black.

The modified code is here:

```
import time
import vtkmodules.all

class vtkTimerCallback():
    def __init__(self, box_data: [int, int, int, int, int, int], box_actor: vtk.vtkActor, mapper: vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper,
                 renderer: vtk.vtkRenderer, interactor: vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor):
        self.timer_count = 0
        self.box_data = box_data
        self.box_actor = box_actor
        self.mapper = mapper
        self.renderer = renderer
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.timerID = None

    def execute(self, obj, event):
        step = 0

        boxes = []
        for i, (box_length, box_width, box_height, x, y, z) in enumerate(self.box_data):
            print(i)
            current_box = [box_length, box_width, box_height, x, y, z]
            print(current_box)
            boxes.append(current_box)
            print(boxes)
            for j, (box_length2, box_width2, box_height2, x2, y2, z2) in enumerate(boxes):
                print(j)
                box = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
                box.SetXLength(box_length2)
                box.SetYLength(box_width2)
                box.SetZLength(box_height2)

                self.mapper.SetInputConnection(box.GetOutputPort())

                self.box_actor.SetMapper(self.mapper)
                self.box_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                self.box_actor.SetPosition(x2, y2, z2)

                self.renderer.AddActor(self.box_actor)
            print(self.box_actor.GetProperty().GetColor())
            interactor = obj
            interactor.GetRenderWindow().Render()
            time.sleep(2)

        if self.timerID:
            interactor.DestroyTimer(self.timerID)


def main():
    # Create the box
    box = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
    box.SetXLength(5)
    box.SetYLength(5)
    box.SetZLength(5)

    # sphere = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
    # sphere.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    # sphere.SetRadius(100)
    # sphere.SetPhiResolution(30)
    # sphere.SetThetaResolution(30)

    # Create mapper and actor
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(box.GetOutputPort())

    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    # actor.SetPosition(0, 0, 0)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

    # setup renderer and interactor
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    render_window.SetWindowName("Animation test")
    render_window.SetSize(600, 600)
    render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)

    # renderer.AddActor(actor)
    # render and interact
    # camera = vtk.vtkCamera()
    # camera.SetPosition(0, -6000, 1000)
    # camera.SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
    # renderer.SetActiveCamera(camera)

    render_window.Render()
    renderer.GetActiveCamera().Zoom(0.2)
    render_window.Render()

    # initialize - prior to creating timer event
    interactor.Initialize()

    box_data = [(5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0),
                (5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0),
                (5, 5, 5, -10, -10, 0),
                (5, 5, 5, -10, 10, 0),
                (5, 5, 5, 10, -10, 0)
                ]

    # sign up to timer event
    cb = vtkTimerCallback(box_data, actor, mapper, renderer, interactor)
    interactor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)
    # This timer sets the time before the animation starts in
    # milliseconds
    cb.timerID = interactor.CreateRepeatingTimer(3000)

    # start the interaction and timer
    render_window.Render()
    interactor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can not figure out if I am doing something wrong, or if what i am trying to do is simply impossible.